# c# powershell collection<PsObject> query with linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, collections, psobject

I am trying to query a powershll object collection in c# by linq..
Can someone help me in this metter...
I have tried following but it does not work although result collection contain 270 psobjects.
How to query it?
Can someone help in this metter..

Collection result = powershell.Invoke();

var resultNumber = result.Where(x => (string)x.Properties["LineURI"].Value == "tel:" + phoneNumber);

Comment: When you say "it does not work", what exactly doesn't work?  Your approach should definitely work, so you should debug it and see what properties each item in the `result` collection has and make sure they have one for `LineURI` which you are searching on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much.
Yes it is working. Probably tried with wrong number.
Thank you very much for confirmation that the expression was correct.

Greetings